# C# MetaTrader5 MT5 read open Orders

Tags: python, c#, metatrader5

I have a program coded in C# ... Also I am working with the Program "MetaTrader 5" MT5 that internally use the language MQL5.

There exists a Python integration for MT5:
https://www.mql5.com/en/docs/integration/python_metatrader5

Unfortunately it seems so that there is no C# integration.
Is there any way around?

I just need to know any open Order (no pending Orders) with its MagicNumber.
From the given Account.

Maybe there will help a short Python-Script? But without any Python Skills i am totally lost.
Did you have any idea, how to get my needed Information? and integrate it to my code?

Answer (score 0):

Try this for python: https://github.com/topics/mt5-api

But I not sure that you can do that without licence